# Regex pattern for space seperated numbers and with two digits in the fractional part

Tags: regex

I need regex that will match space seperated numbers (**max nine numbers and max three numbers in group**) and with one or two digits in the fractional part.
Like:

`1`
`1 000`
`0,01`
`1 000,1`
`1 000,10`
`11 000`
`1 111 111`
`111 111 111`
`111 111 111,11`

should not match:
`,75`
`1111 11`
`1 1 34`

so far I have `^[0-9]{1,9}(,[0-9]{1,2})?$` but it fails with spaces.

Comment: Use `^(?:[0-9]{1,9}|[0-9]{1,3}(?: [0-9]{3}){0,2})(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UFpI5X/2)

Comment: `real numbers (only two)` what do you mean by this, can you elaborate ?

Comment: @CodeManiac By `real numbers` I mean those numbers after comma

Comment: I think *only two* means *max two digits in the fractional part*

Comment: Do you mean you also want to match `1 1 34`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it should not match `1 1 34` but rather `1 134`.

Comment: So you basically want a currency validator which maxes out at `999 999 999,99`?

Comment: Is `,75` valid?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No `,75` it's not valid but rather `0,75`

Comment: @mardok See my updated answer.

Comment: @CodeManiac I see, thanks it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,9}|[0-9]{1,3}(?: [0-9]{3}){0,2})(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Or,  if you plan to support any whitespace

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,9}|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s[0-9]{3}){0,2})(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UFpI5X/3).

To support any amount of digit groupings, replace `{0,2}` with `*`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[0-9]{1,9}|[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s[0-9]{3}){0,2})` - 1 to 9 digits or 1 to 3 digits followed with 0, 1 or 2 occurrences of space and 3 digits
- `(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of `,` and 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are requesting a currency format validator which maxes out at `999 999 999,99` and the `,99` is optional:

```
^\d{1,3}(?: \d{3}){0,2}(,\d{1,2})?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/mapnlq/1

Comment: This is bad practice to use an identical pattern at the start and end of the quantified group as in `^(?: ?\d ?){1,9}(,\d{1,2})?$`. Here, the `?` and `{1,9}` will mitigate the risk (practically eliminating it), but generally, this kind of patterns should be avoided.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. I changed it to `(?:\d ?){1,9}` after realizing that double-spaces are not present in OP's accepted data. There could be edge cases where ` *` (space star) would be more appropriate but that's just conjecture.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus if you remove optional space before it wont match strings having space at the start of string

Comment: @CodeManiac OP's examples do not present that as an acceptable pattern.

Comment: It fails for `1 1 34`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe,

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s[0-9]{1,3})?(?:\s[0-9]{1,3})?(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

might be close to what you have in mind.

---

Here we've assumed that a number followed by a <kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>,</kbd> would be invalid, such as:

> 111 111<kbd>space</kbd>
>
> 111 111 111<kbd>,</kbd>

and a bit simple-to-read version would be:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\s[0-9]{1,3}){0,2}(?:,[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eUEt5a/1)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/fFD4ZV/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/fFD4ZV/1debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: It fails for `1 1 34`